# Add a group to members of a group in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory-group

I would like to add a group to members of another group using PowerShell. I have seen a way to do that with vbscript but is it possible to do it with powershell?

My environment:
-Windows Server 2008 R2
-PowerShell 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is using [ActiveDirectory module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity <samaccountname of destination group> -Members <samaccountname of group to add in>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have also succeed to do it using: dsquery group (...) |dsmod group -addmbr (...)

Comment: @fdubrez. U'r welcome. Dsquery doesn't need powershell. In Powershell Quest (I love it) & ActiveDirectory modules are the best way for administering AD objects!

Answer (score 0):

This script copies the group members inside another specified group

```
$Source_Group = "CN=SourceGroupName,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com"
$Destination_Group = "CN=DestinationGroupName,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com"

$Target = Get-QADGroupMember $Source_Group
foreach ($Person in $Target) {
    add-QADGroupMember -identity $Destination_Group -member $Person.dn
}
```

[Source](https://sites.google.com/site/powershellandphp/powershell-1/active-directory/copy-group-members-to-another-group)

Comment: you must remember that this code requires the Quest snap-in to works. And result isn't equivalent to a nested group.

Comment: I can't install third party tools but thanks for your answer. The usage of dsquery and dsmod do the job without the quest snap-in.